# hp deskjet 3630 printing blank/weird pages

Tags: printing

I have a HP Deskjet 3630 series printer. Whenever, I try to print the pages are blank.

What I have tried so far, with no luck:

- Replaced the ink cartridge with new HP cartridge

-Ran through the diagnostic doctor process

I get no errors at all

Any/All help is appreciated
!

Comment: What does blank or weird mean? What does it print when it’s weird?

Comment: @Appleoddity just like lines or very small, missing text

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a corrupted page transmission.

Try disconnecting the printer from power and computer for at least a minute which is the prescribed way of resetting your printer btw.

Make sure the print queue is empty.

If it doesn't help contact HP.